# Separate Background Image For Mobile Devices

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, background

My website is [http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/](http://%20www.rosstheexplorer.com)

On mobiles the background image is too small for my liking.

I am using the plugin 'Add background-size to Customizer' to reduce the height of the background image. On desktops I did not want the background taking up the whole page.

Can I change the dimensions of the background image for mobiles or have an entirely separate image? Is there a plugin that can achieve this or is there some CSS code I could use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use entirely separate image or even resize the image to your liking by using media queries. For e.g.,
For desktop,

```
.block {
  background-image: url('images/bg1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 500px;
}
```

For mobile (say iphone 6+),

```
@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  background-image: url('images/bg2.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 500px;
}
```

OR

```
@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  background-image: url('images/bg1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it took me a few times to get the web link for the picture correct. Eventually I used https://i1.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Cover-Photo-6-2.jpg".

Comment: Where/in which file can I configure the proposed changes?

Answer (score 0):

`Can I change the dimensions of the background image for mobiles or have an entirely separate image?` - Yes, you can achieve this by using CSS media queries for mobile. You can both - provide different dimensions or give a different image.

To know more about media queries, refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)